# Difference between passing property on the command line and in the pom file

Tags: maven

It seems I have misunderstood how maven properties work, and I need help.

I made the following minimal pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>cross-compile-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <javafx.platform>linux</javafx.platform>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

I would expect that this will fetch the linux dependency regardless of the platform I'm running on. However, what happens when running on Windows is the following (output from mvn dependency:tree):

```
[INFO] org.example:cross-compile-test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:win:11.0.2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO]       \- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:win:11.0.2:compile
[...]
```

The strange thing is that it works correctly when adding `-Djavafx.platform=linux`. To my understanding this should be equivalent to my existing pom file. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have tried using ```properties-maven-plugin``` with ```set-system-properties``` but that seems to make no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is most likely the order of resolution:

1. Command line properties are set
2. Dependencies are resolved
3. Properties from the `pom.xml` are read

So your dependencies don't know about the properties in the POM.